# Async/await: Making method async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, async-await

I'm trying to do a simple example but I'm not even getting the basics. What's wrong with this code? Imagine `Calculate()` takes a few seconds.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int result = await Calculate();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task<int> Calculate()
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: use the "classical" method to get the result out of your task inside main ;)

Comment: You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change your main to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int result = Calculate().Result;

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As soon as you use the `await` keyword, the surrounding method must be marked as `async` which - as others metnioned - is not possible for `Main`.
Since `async` methods like `Calculate` still return good old `Task` objects, feel free to use the "old" way of dealing with them: using `Result` to wait for results. Of course this is a blocking operation - but no reason to be non-blocking inside `Main`, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
static void Main()
{
    WrapMain();
}

static async void WrapMain()
{
    int result = await Calculate();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task<int> Calculate()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return 1;
    });
}
```